# How to redirect to next page in HTML when the video length is over?

Tags: html

I have a website in HTML. On the `HomePage` of the website there is a video playing on it. I want when the video is over that is when video duration is over then the site redirected to the next page automatically.
How could i do this in HTML?

Comment: You can't. You need JavaScript for that.

Comment: How can i do the same using javascript? @Quentin

Answer (score 3):

Familiarize yourself with the HTML5 video element, as it seems like it'll come in handy for you.

So say you have a video like;

```
<video src="myVideo.mp4">
</video>
```

You can then use the onended HTML5 event to do a function when the video has ended such as;

```
<script>
var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];

video.onended = function(e) {
  /*Do things here!*/
};
</script>
```

See here for more detail: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-ended